# How to log messages in webpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgi, web.py

I am using wsgi as suggested in the cookbook, and it logs the webpy messages into the log. I am really struggling with adding my own messages to the logs.
eg: I want to add query parameters and other warnings.

Answer (score 1):

For those with similar problems please use:

```
logger = web.ctx.env.get('wsgilog.logger')
```

to get the logger and then,

```
logger.info('hello world')
```

to log the message